# Include an early version of android framework JAR in my application APK?

Tags: android, jar, apk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have built an Android app that worked fine on Android 2.3.* and 4.0.*. However, after upgrading my device to Jelly Bean (4.1.1), I found my app does not work properly (crashes, ANRs, etc.) any more.

As a temporary workaround, I am wondering if it is possible to pack an earlier version (say Android 2.3) of the Android framework JAR into my APK and force all my code to use classes/APIs in that JAR?

I think including the JAR in my APK should be easier. But I have no idea how I could force my code to use classes/APIs in the JAR during run-time.

I know it is not a decent fix (hacking, package size, legal issue, etc.) even it will work. But I am just curious whether it is feasible.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated!

### (Edit)

I have tried the following:

1. Extracted the **/system/framework/framework.odex** from an Android 2.3 ROM;
2. Deodexed it and converted it into a JAR file (say framework.jar);
3. I verified framework.jar and it contains the actual framework code, not stub methods;
4. Put framework.jar into the libs folder of my project and built out the APK;
5. I verified the result APK and the android framework classes are indeed included.

However, it seems my code is still using the classes/APIs of the actual version of SDK installed in the Android device. :(

### (Edit)

It seems all the framework/core classes are already pre-loaded from the device (/system/framework/framework.odex) by Zygote during system boot-up time, for performance reason. So even I have included those classes in our APK, the pre-loaded ones will still be instantiated instead.

This sounds like a dead end to me... :(

Comment: that's probably not a good idea.. you can limit your app downloads through the maxSdk property in your manifest. then fix your bugs and remove it ..

Comment: Sorry Ran, unfortunately excluding Jelly Bean is probably not an option to me now ... :(

Answer (score 3):

> As a temporary workaround, I am wondering if it is possible to pack an earlier version (say Android 2.3) of the Android framework JAR into my APK and force all my code to use classes/APIs in that JAR?

That is not possible, sorry. What you think of as "the Android framework JAR" has no code -- it is merely stub implementations of the classes and methods exposed in the Android SDK. The real Android framework resides in the firmware, and you cannot replace it.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! Yes I was aware of the fact that the SDK android.jar contains only stub methods. I have updated my question with some further information.

Comment: @TonyBlues: "However, it seems my code is still using the classes/APIs of the actual version of SDK installed in the Android device" -- of course. As I wrote, the real Android framework resides in the firmware, **and you cannot replace it**.

Comment: You're right, Mark. This seems to be a dead end. I probably will try harder to fix those actual issues. Thanks!